# How to dynamically add scripts into the head tag when angular component has loaded

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a script tag that has a skype web control cdn in it, the script tag has been inserted in the head of my index.html, now the script tag is called before the component I need it in has loaded, any ideas on how I can reference this script in my component?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I've figured it out, what you need to do is dynamically create the script tag and then append it to the head of your document:

```js
export class Component {

//...

loadScript() {
  let node = document.createElement('script'); // creates the script tag
  node.src = ''; // sets the source (insert url in between quotes)
  node.type = 'text/javascript'; // set the script type
  node.async = true; // makes script run asynchronously
  node.charset = 'utf-8';
  // append to head of document
  document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(node); 
}

ngOnInit{
  loadScript();
}
```

Comment: Can you confirm this is safe to use as we're manipulating the DOM?

Comment: @DragosStanciu yes this is safe to use

Comment: You may want to wait until the script fully loaded. See [this](http://www.lukasjakob.com/how-to-dynamically-load-external-scripts-in-angular/)

Answer (score 1):

> script tag is called before the component I need it in has loaded, any ideas on how I can reference this script in my component

Most script tags export a *global* variable. E.g `React` `$` `_` etc. Read the docs on the lib and use the global variable they export.