# Load third party js in head tag using angular json + environment based

Tags: javascript, json, angular, typescript

I want to add my google analytics JS in the HEAD tag. so I can try to configure with angular.json

```
"scripts": [
              "src/assets/js/jquery-3.4.1.min.js",
              "src/assets/js/general.js",
              { "input": "src/assets/js/google-analytics.js", "lazy": false }
            ]
```

but, not add in the head tag, all js are added at the end of the body tag.

one other option is, will add directly in index.html. but I need to add base on the environment.

Please share if any way to add JS in HEAD tag directly using **angular.json**

Comment: I think this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46923628/how-to-dynamically-add-scripts-into-the-head-tag-when-angular-component-has-load

Comment: Yes, but I am searching direct solutions with angular.json with environment condition if there any. otherwise can go with index.html + file replace option of angular.json or answers of these duplicate questions. thanks

Answer (score -1):

try to add your JavaScript file at the top of head tag inside the index.html file of our main app.

you will find it at project-name/src/index.html

Comment: Sorry, I know, can use index.html for that. but I am searching for a dynamic solution with environment condition

Answer (score -1):

To load js file externally from assets

create service file add file to the assets and write path in array.

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";


    declare var document: any;
    @Injectable({
        providedIn:'root'
    })
    export class ScriptService {
      private scripts: any = {};

      constructor() {
        ScriptConstant.forEach((script: any) => {
          this.scripts[script.name] = {
            loaded: false,
            src: script.src
          };
        });
      }

      load(...scripts: string[]) {
        var promises: any[] = [];
        scripts.forEach(script => promises.push(this.loadScript(script)));
        return Promise.all(promises);
      }
      loadAll() {
        var promises: any[] = [];
        ScriptConstant.forEach(script => {
          // promises.push(delay(1000));
          promises.push(this.loadScript(script.name));
        });
        return Promise.all(promises);
      }

      loadScript(name: string) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          //resolve if already loaded
          if (this.scripts[name].loaded) {
            resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Already Loaded" });
          } else {
            //load script
            let script = document.createElement("script");
            script.type = "text/javascript";
            script.src = this.scripts[name].src;
            if (script.readyState) {
              //IE
              script.onreadystatechange = () => {
                if (
                  script.readyState === "loaded" ||
                  script.readyState === "complete"
                ) {
                  script.onreadystatechange = null;
                  this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                  resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Loaded" });
                }
              };
            } else {
              //Others
              script.onload = () => {
                this.scripts[name].loaded = true;
                resolve({ script: name, loaded: true, status: "Loaded" });
              };
            }
            script.onerror = (error: any) =>
              resolve({ script: name, loaded: false, status: "Loaded" });
            document.getElementsByTagName("body")[0].appendChild(script);
          }
        });
      }
    }

    interface Scripts {
        name: string;
        src: string;
      }
      export const ScriptConstant: Scripts[] = [
        { name: "multislider", src: "assets/js/multislider.js" },

      ];
```

Inject this ScriptService wherever you need it and load js libs like this

```
this.script.load('multislider').then(data => {
    console.log('script loaded ', data);
}).catch(error => console.log(error));
```

Comment: The behavior of this service is not the same as building the scripts directly into index.html at start. This service will actually introduce a delay, and not inject the script into index.html until the service is ran. And this answer does not answer the question about loading scripts using `angular.json`.