# How to remove script tags in index.html from Angular Component

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6, angular8, typescript2.0

```
<script data-jsd-embedded data-base-url="" data-key="" type="text/javascript" src="js-text-sample.js"></script>
```

Above is my sample script tag which is on index.html

I want to hide it inside an Angular component.

The angular component will fetch a config first from the API. Then it will validate if it needs to hide the script or not.

The script is a embedded widget that I need to hide if its false on the config API.

How do I hide it from the component code?

Comment: try:     <script *ngIf="shouldHide" data-jsd-embedded data-base-url="" data-key="" type="text/javascript" src="js-text-sample.js"></script>

Comment: @luke jon we cannot use ng-if inside index.html in Angular project.

Comment: You could create the script-tag inside of angular, if it should be included. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46924372/11028838

Comment: A script tag is not visible, so what do you mean by "hiding" a script tag?

Comment: I mean remove the script tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of placing script tag and worrying about after logic to hide/show, why don't you create script tag at runtime based on result.

```
import { Renderer2, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { DOCUMENT } from '@angular/common';

class MyComponent implements OnInit {

    constructor(
        private _renderer2: Renderer2, 
        @Inject(DOCUMENT) private _document: Document
    ) { }

    public ngOnInit() {

        let script = this._renderer2.createElement('script');
        script.src='_SOURCE_HERE_'
        `;

        this._renderer2.appendChild(this._document.body, script);
    }
}
```

Comment: you can also create a method which can handle add/remove for you of script tag by id, sorry I didn't show above code

Comment: how do I add these elements on the <script> when appending? (data-jsd-embedded data-base-url="" data-key="")

Comment: script.setAttribute('data-jsd-embedded', '');
script.setAttribute('data-base-url', '');
script.setAttribute('data-key', '');

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't work

Comment: it was working for me give me a moment I will give you stackblitz link

Comment: check here https://angular-vmjbxk.stackblitz.io.
Inspect element you will script in the head

Comment: Editor URL https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vmjbxk?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: @AnthonyCuartero let me know if you got it and please accept an answer, it will help people with similar questions

Comment: Yep it works man. Thanks. I can see it on the html. But the widget didn't load. I don't why. I'll just dig into this.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it the clasic, javascript way. When you get your response from the api, query the DOM to get a reference to the element and remove it:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('widgetContainerId');
element.parentElement.removeChild(element);
```

This will remove the widget from the DOM.

If later during the lifecycle of the application you want to show it again, then you should not remove the whole element from the DOM, but hide it, maybe with `display: none;`:

```js
const element = document.getElementById('widgetContainerId');
element.style.display = 'none';
```

Whenever you need it to be visible again, update the display property to something else, like `block`:

```js
element.style.display = 'block';
```

Comment: this doesn't work. The widget still shows.

Comment: You should hide (or remove) the widget itself, not the `script` element.